# Django - Setting AUTH_USER_MODEL

Tags: python, django

I have created a Django project named `Backend` and in that, I have created an app called `Tool`.

Now, I have created a `User` model by **inheriting** the `AbstractUser` model and I have created 2 **accounts** using this model.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_mentor  = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Student(models.Model):
    user       = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    college    = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...

class Mentor(models.Model):
    user       = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

I have updated the `settings.py` in `Backend` folder in this way:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'Tool.User'
```

After `makemigrations` and `migrate`, I am getting the following error:

> ValueError: Related model 'Tool.User' cannot be resolved

---

**Traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Sreekar Mouli\Documents\Mini Project\Backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Sreekar Mouli\Documents\Mini Project\Backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Sreekar Mouli\Documents\Mini Project\Backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Sreekar Mouli\Documents\Mini Project\Backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Sreekar Mouli\Documents\Mini Project\Backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sreekar Mouli\Documents\Mini Project\Backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 203, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "C:\Users\Sreekar Mouli\Documents\Mini Project\Backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\Sreekar Mouli\Documents\Mini Project\Backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\Sreekar Mouli\Documents\Mini Project\Backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\Sreekar Mouli\Documents\Mini Project\Backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Users\Sreekar Mouli\Documents\Mini Project\Backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\models.py", line 91, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "C:\Users\Sreekar Mouli\Documents\Mini Project\Backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 263, in create_model
    definition, extra_params = self.column_sql(model, field)
  File "C:\Users\Sreekar Mouli\Documents\Mini Project\Backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 157, in column_sql
    db_params = field.db_parameters(connection=self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\Sreekar Mouli\Documents\Mini Project\Backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 966, in db_parameters
    return {"type": self.db_type(connection), "check": self.db_check(connection)}
  File "C:\Users\Sreekar Mouli\Documents\Mini Project\Backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 963, in db_type
    return self.target_field.rel_db_type(connection=connection)
  File "C:\Users\Sreekar Mouli\Documents\Mini Project\Backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 878, in target_field
    return self.foreign_related_fields[0]
  File "C:\Users\Sreekar Mouli\Documents\Mini Project\Backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 632, in foreign_related_fields
    return tuple(rhs_field for lhs_field, rhs_field in self.related_fields if rhs_field)
  File "C:\Users\Sreekar Mouli\Documents\Mini Project\Backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 619, in related_fields
    self._related_fields = self.resolve_related_fields()
  File "C:\Users\Sreekar Mouli\Documents\Mini Project\Backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 604, in resolve_related_fields
    raise ValueError('Related model %r cannot be resolved' % self.remote_field.model)
```

Comment: also can you share your related migration files?

Comment: Have you installed your application (list in `INSTALLED_APPS`)?

Comment: @ruddra, I have added the stacktrace. And, yes I have listed my app in `INSTALLED_APPS` @vishes_shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have **cleared all the previous migrations, dropped the db and re-created** it. When I run `makemigrations` and `migrate`, it worked fine.

Seems like there were some issues with previous migrations. But, it's confusing and wierd that it was showing this error.

> ValueError: Related model 'Tool.User' cannot be resolved

Answer (score 2):

What is your app name? The letter size is important

aplication "Tool", model "User"

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    "Tool",
)
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'Tool.User'
```

and in case you are going to import user to other files, better do it this way

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
```

And try to make new migrations. If you do not want to add depenses.

Comment: My app's name is `Tool`, I have mentioned that in the first line. `INSTALLED_APPS = ("Tool", )` `AUTH_USER_MODEL='Tool.User'`. This is how my `settings.py` is.

Comment: better name applications with small letters :) Tool looks like a class name. This is not necessarily but makes easier code maintaining

Comment: Ya, I will work on those namings. The error still exists!!

Comment: looks like migrations problem. 
Can u return to previous migration? and make new again

Comment: Seems like migrations was the problem. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are facing issues when changing the [USER model in middle of project](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project). This change can't be done automatically, and needs to be done manually. As per [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25313), you can follow these steps to manually migrate user model:

1. Create a custom user model identical to auth.User, call it User (so many-to-many tables keep the same name) and set `db_table='auth_user'` (so it uses the same table)
2. Throw away all your migrations
3. Recreate a fresh set of migrations
4. make a backup of your database
5. Truncate the django_migrations table
6. Fake-apply the new set of migrations
7. Unset db_table, make other changes to the custom model, generate migrations, apply them

If you have the luxury to delete the DB then you can follow @SreekarMouli's answer.